# How do I Force User friendly URLs In sharepoint for a My Site Collection

Tags: sharepoint-2010

Disregarding my question I asked earlier (and deleted) which has been solved, I want to know, how do I force sharepoint to generate user-friendly my site collection URLs?

To make the question easier, I'll include an example.

```
http://spaces.companyspttest.biz/Person.aspx?accountname=ADtest\Eon
```

must become

```
http://spaces.companyspttest.biz/Eon
```

How do I do this?

Comment: wow. is sharepoint really that infamous that I barely get views

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, seems like what I have been looking for is a Self-Service Site Creation.

To activate it , go to Web applications management in Central Administration in Sharepoint, ,Select the web application which requires this "Shortened URL",Click Self Service Site Creation in the ribbon, and turn it on.

After that, add a Managed path to the web application called Profiles.

Not 10000% what I wanted regarding the URL, but definitely the page I wanted to see when I type the URL.

Comment: Talking to myself, Will add this answer to wiki.